# React: Why am I getting callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a callback function in my async code but I am getting the error "callback is not a function". What am I doing wrong? I created the callBack function separately and passed it to the async function as a parameter then called it my react component

```
 function myCallBack() {
     setTopicLoaded(true);
 }

//async function
export function fetchGroupTopic(groupAdminId, myCallback) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getTopic());
    try {
      const myTopic = [];
      if (groupAdminId) {
        const response = firestore
          .collection("topic")
          .where("adminId", "==", groupAdminId);
        const data = await response.get();
        data.docs.forEach((item) => {
          let id = item.id;
          let data = item.data();

          myTopic.push({ id, ...data });
        });
        myCallback();
        dispatch(setGroupTopic(myTopic));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch(getTopicFailure());
    }
  };
}

// calling it here
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (myGroup.length) {
      fetchGroupTopic(myGroup[0].adminId,myCallBack);

    }
  }, [id, submitted, myGroup]);
```

Comment: How are you defining the `myCallBack` reference in the `useEffect()`? I'm assuming it's not called `myCallback`, but it's still important to know how that function is being defined (and also imported, if that's how you're doing it)

Comment: May you provide the exact error?

Comment: @thebigfundamentals the error i am getting is "callBack is not a function"

Comment: Since your callback is called `myCallBack`, I believe that is the error. Providing precise info will help in getting better answers. Are you importing the function `myCallBack` or is it all inside the same file? If you are importing/exporting, please provide info about how it has been done.

Comment: @Samathingamajig the name of the function is "myCallBack", I am calling it in my UseEffect

Comment: Please, could you provide your `stack trace`.